# "Chaining" @future calls

Tags: future

How is the chaining of future call achieved in example from  Dan Appleman book http://advancedapex.com/samplecode/ ? I am trying to insert 200/220 records and see that only one future is forced.

```
public static void GoingAsync3(List<Solution> solutionlist, Map<ID, Solution> oldmap, Boolean isInsert)
    {
        if(AlreadyProcessed) return;
        AlreadyProcessed = true;
        for(Solution sl:solutionlist)
        {
            if(isInsert || sl.SolutionNote!= oldmap.get(sl.id).SolutionNote) sl.TranslationPending__c = true; 
        }
        ThirdAttemptRequestAsync();
    }


public static void ThirdAttemptRequestAsync()
    {
        GoAsyncHelper__c asynchelper = GetAsyncHelper();
        if(ThirdAttemptAsyncRequested) return;  // Already fired a request in this context
        if(asynchelper.AsyncPending__c) return; // Someone already requested async operation

        asynchelper.AsyncPending__c = true;
        Database.Update(asynchelper);

        if(!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch() && !System.isScheduled())
        {
            ThirdAttemptAsyncRequested = true;
            ThirdAttemptAsync();
        }
    }

@future
    private static void ThirdAttemptAsync()
    {
        GoAsyncHelper__c asynchelper = GetAsyncHelper();
        if(asynchelper.AsyncPending__c)
        {   // Clear any pending request
            asynchelper.AsyncPending__c = false;
            Database.Update(asynchelper);
        }

        ThirdAttemptSync();
    }

    public static void ThirdAttemptSync()
    {
        Integer availablecallouts = Limits.getLimitCallouts() - Limits.getCallouts();
        if(availablecallouts < 2)
        {
            ThirdAttemptRequestAsync();
            return;
        }
        List<Solution> solutionstoupdate = [SELECT ID, SolutionNote, SolutionSpanish__c from Solution where LastModifiedDate > :DateTime.Now().addHours(-24) And TranslationPending__c = true LIMIT :availablecallouts];
        for(Solution sl: solutionstoupdate) sl.SolutionSpanish__c = SimulateTranslationCallout(sl.SolutionNote);
        update solutionstoupdate;

        if(solutionstoupdate.size()== availablecallouts)
        {
            ThirdAttemptRequestAsync();
        }
    }

    public static GoAsyncHelper__c GetAsyncHelper()
    {
        GoAsyncHelper__c theobject = GoAsyncHelper__c.getInstance('default');
        if(theobject==null) 
        {
            theobject = new GoAsyncHelper__c();
            theobject.name = 'default';
            theobject.AsyncPending__c = false;
            Database.Insert(theobject);
        }
        return theobject;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question that we can help with? If you are looking for help with code that you found in Dan's book, it is probably best to contact him directly. What, exactly, are you trying to do here?

Comment: These code run only one future method but in the book described as it performs future chaining. And I can't get how chaining is achieved in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

[The System class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_methods_system_system) contains the [isFuture()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_isFuture) method that returns true if the currently executing code is invoked by code contained in a method annotated with future; false otherwise.

As you can see, the ThirdAttemptRequestAsync() method in the example provided contains an if statement which checks if the code is run from a feature method. The following logic is executed only if the previous check returns false:

```
 if(!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch() && !System.isScheduled())
    {
        ThirdAttemptAsyncRequested = true;
        ThirdAttemptAsync();
    }
```